# How to restore a project into eclipse from .metadata file

Tags: eclipse

Actually my workspace folder become corrupted and after restoring I can only fully recover the metadata folder. So, now how to recover the entire project from .metedata folder? Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `.metedata` folder does not contain copies of the content of the projects. But it might be the case that **some files** can be restored **via *Restore from Local History...***.

In Eclipse the projects are shown as closed, right? Do the following for each project:

1. **Right-click** the closed project folder and choose ***Properties*** and in ***Resource*** get the ***Location***
2. **Create the directory** of this location
3. In the created directory **create a `.project` file** with the template given below where *ProjectName* is replaced by the project name shown in Eclipse
4. **Restart Eclipse**
5. **Open the project**
6. **Right-click** the project and choose  ***Restore from Local History...***
7. Good luck!

`.project` template:

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>ProjectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```